# WSO2 ESB Dynamic Configuration for Inbound Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I configured an inbound endpoint, but I want to manage `java.naming.provider.url` value in a conf.xml file that under config directory in WSO2.

In each environment I have a conf.xml file which includes the URL values for that environment like:

```
<environment>
    <JNPU>test</JNPU>
</environment>
<test>
    <JNPU>failover:tcp://localhost:61616</JNPU>
</test>
```

I just want first read this environment value of the JNPU which is test in this example. Then, I want to change the `java.naming.provider.url` value in inbound endpoint with this value.

In a sequence, I can read the values with using these properties:

```
<property name="confFile" expression="get-property('registry','conf:endpoints/conf.xml')" scope="default" type="OM" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
<property name="JNPUEnvValue" expression="evaluate(fn:concat('$confFile//environment//','JNPU'))" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
<property name="JNPUValue" expression="evaluate(fn:concat('$ctx:epConfiguration','//',get-property('JNPUEnvValue'),'//','JNPU'))" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

I used them as parameters in inbound endpoint but I could not get the value of `java.naming.provider.url` in conf.xml file.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can dynamically configure inbound endpoint parameters, if we save only the respective parameter value as the content of the file saved in registry. For example, in your case, the value "failover:tcp://localhost:61616" should be saved in the file. You can keep separate files for each parameter in a registry location. And, you need to only change file content for each environment.

Please refer the section **Specifying inbound endpoint parameters as registry values** at https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/WSO2+EI+Inbound+Endpoints.

Comment: Hi. I need more detail about the file content. Could you explain what should be the file content and the file extension at the directory of conf:/repository/ei/ei-configurations/test?

Comment: You should have only the url value, "failover:tcp://localhost:61616" within the file. And, the file can be a text file without an extension.

Comment: Hi @prabushi samarakoon, I tried but when I check the inbound endpoint  configuration in WSO2 console, java.naming.provider.url value is $registry:gov:/javaNamingProviderURL which is the path of the javaNamingProviderURL file. I added the file directly to the governance folder by the way.

Comment: OK, Solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I also need to manage value of the `coordination` parameter value with a conf file. I tried with using the same way, but I am not sure it is about boolean value or not, when I check the configuration in WSO2,although the file content is "false", the parameter value in the WSO2 console is default "true". Is there any way to manage it with a file? @prabushi samarakoon

Answer (score 1):

If you can keep the url in the registry, then you can use it from the registry as follows.

```
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" key="gov:/Path/javaNamingProviderURL"/>
```

Comment: Could you inform me about the what sould be the content of the file and file extension more? Also, in each environment I should upload the file that contains proper URL information for the environment which that I do not want. I have a configuration file already that I managed the APIs endpoint information. I just want to add the inbound endpoint information there. If I can read the value of the java.naming.provider.url in any file, this is also OK for me, but I need more information about the file content and file extension.

Comment: In the registry entry, just add the JNP URL.